# SQL How can I find out who has no entry?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a large table in which various entries are written. i want to find out who has not answered a questionnaire. once the questionnaire has been answered, an entry is created in the column `'tableName'` with the name `'ExperienceSampling'`.

With the following query I can find out who answered the questionnaire how often, but not who never answered it.
How do I manage to see also entries with `participantId` = 0?

```
SELECT participantId, COUNT(tableName)  
FROM log  
WHERE `tableName` = 'ExperienceSampling'  
GROUP BY `participantId` ORDER BY `COUNT(tableName)` ASC
```

Comment: You need a list of all the partiticpants somewhere.  Where is that?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation in MySQL to get all participants in the log table:

```
SELECT participantId, SUM(`tableName` = 'ExperienceSampling') as cnt
FROM log  
GROUP BY `participantId`
ORDER BY cnt ASC ;
```

If you have a separate list of participants, then I would recommend using that:

```
select p.partipantId, sum(l.participantId)
from participants p left join
     log l
     on l.participantId = p.participantId and
        l.tableName = 'ExperienceSampling'
group by p.partipantId;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't have a seperate list with all partiticpants yet, the first one works great!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some `user` table or `participants` table for signed up users, you can get the list of all the users who have not logged an entry by doing the following

```
SELECT participantTable.id
FROM participantTable where participantTable.id 
NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT participantId  
FROM log  
WHERE `tableName` = 'ExperienceSampling'  
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming if a participant never answered the questionnaire, there would be no entries in the `log` table. If that is the case, you will need to `LEFT/RIGHT JOIN` the `log` table with the table that contains participants. Joining two tables this way will return ALL of the entries from one table but only the matching entries from the other. So, if you `LEFT JOIN` the `log` table to the table containing unique participants, you can add a condition to return only results that did not have any matches. For example:

```
SELECT p.ID
FROM participantTable as p LEFT JOIN log as l
ON p.ID = l.participantID
WHERE l.participantID IS NULL
```